# VB working with SQL DB - end of row count, keeps looping

Tags: sql, vb.net, loops

I'm adding to a combo box an ID and a name that I'm pulling from a database. My problem is that for some reason my loop doesn't end once it reaches the end of the records in the database table. Here's my code:

```
    For intcount = 0 To dtOrders.Rows.Count - 1
        cmbSearch.Items.Add(dtOrders.Rows(intcount)("EmployeeID").ToString & " " &
           dtOrders.Rows(intcount)("EmployeeLastName").ToString & ", " &
           dtOrders.Rows(intcount)("EmployeeFirstName").ToString)
    Next
```

Shouldn't the .rows.count - 1 stop it once it reaches the last record? It loops 4 times through.

Comment: What query are you using to load dtOrders?  Maybe you're getting back more than you think.  Have you run the query to see the result set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're not getting back four times as many rows as you expect in dtOrders?

I'm guessing, from the name "dtOrders", that you're using a query that joins together customer and order information and therefore you will get the customer represented once for each order.

Comment: You nailed it, sort of. My select statement was pulling another employee ID value from another table that i planned on using later. I thought i could get away with using 1 select statement, oh well. 

Thanks